# iOS, Pods: Special dir for some pods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I tried to install some pods and two of them were installed from local place.

```
pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', :local => '~/Documents/hupods/Mapbox-iOS-SDK'
```

After successful installation I found that the pods installed from GitHub were placed `Pods target / Pods` folder but the local pods for some reason the system has placed in `Pods target / Development Pods`. Now I've got issues with linking the .h files of the local pods.

Why did it happen? How to install the local pods into the same Pods directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct and `Development Pods` is a group and not a folder and thus does not affect the header file lookup.

If you use `:local` (which should read `:path` instead) then CocoaPods will create symlinks from `Pods/Headers/Public/<pod name>/<header name>.h` to your local pod. So it just works the same way it does for regular pods.

How do you import the headers? What is the error? How do the `.podspec` and `Podfile` look like?

Comment: import: #import "RMFoundation.h"b -> file missing

Comment: Podfile looks like ^ see above. Podspec was downloaded from git.

Comment: Ok. let me try to reinstall pods

Comment: Same result. Linking error. RMFoundation.h file not found.

Comment: It's `#import <Mapbox-iOS-SDK/RMFoundation.h>`. It's also important that this header file is covered by the public header files entry in the pod's `.podspec`.

Comment: The document RMAnnotation.h could not be autosaved. The file does't exist.

Comment: Does `<project path>/Pods/Headers/Public/Mapbox-iOS-SDK/RMFoundation.h` exist?

Comment: Foundation does not exist in the dir. Foundation is not listed in .podspec. Hmmm

Comment: Include into podspec and reinstall?

Comment: By the way, what is the right tool to modify the  '.podspec' files?

Comment: Any text editor. You can set the editor to Ruby syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thank you for your help it didn't solve all the issues, but you helped me a lot. Upvote & Accept!

Comment: Also check out my other answer as it is related to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Mapbox SDK 1.6.1: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/issues/631

I suggest using version 1.6.0 for now.